# How to Click a SPAN with Dynamic Id

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, tags

I am trying to Click on a certain Link within a SPAN tag, I tried using XPath, but the Id is different each time when the Page is loaded

For example if my xpath was `.//*[@id='mi_205']/span[2]` for the Code below

```
<ul id="197" class="menu sub-menu" role="menu" data-parent="mi_196" style="z-index: 20000; top: 139px; left: 47px;">
<li id="mi_199" class="menu-item" role="menuitem" title="View contents" command="view-content" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore;">
<li id="mi_201" class="menu-item" role="menuitem" title="View history" command="view-history" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore;">
<li id="mi_203" class="menu-item menu-item-separator" role="separator" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore;">
<li id="mi_205" class="menu-item hover focus" role="menuitem" title="Add file(s)..." command="add-new-file" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore;">
<span class="icon bowtie-icon bowtie-math-plus-light"/>
<span class="text">Add file(s)...</span>
<span class="html"/>
</li>
```

Next time the XPath Changes to something else and so the XPath that I mentioned is no longer Valid. I wanted to click on the Link which reads "Add Files".

Comment: Its the same with CSS Selector

Answer (score 1):

You can use CssSelector. Your selector would be something like this:

```
"li[command='add-new-file']"
```

Here is a link that should help you with some nifty ccs selector tricks:
["The Skinny on CSS Attribute Selectors"](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other li items under it and add files is always the last li, you can use;

```
//ul/li[last()]
```